# How to keep showing stale React component until fresh one is ready

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

In React 18, I want to keep displaying a stale component while a fresh one is initialising asynchronously. The new one needs to do some fetching and preparation after mount, and I don't want it to cause flickering by appearing directly after mount with the wrong size.

The documentation for `Suspense` and `startTransition` makes it seem like this should be doable, but there are these caveats:

- `Suspense` only works with:

  - lazy-loaded components (doesn't help as I need to suspend past the loading stage)
  - certain frameworks like Next.js (I'm in an Electron app)
- `startTransition` only keeps the old component around when used together with Suspense

So is it even possible right now?

Or do I need to hack together some custom solution that uses placeholders, or that renders both components with one hidden, flipping visibility at the right moment?

Answer (score 0):

In my own App, I have separate components to load data versus display the results. You might google dumb component / smart component for more info.

For example, `DataLoader.tsx` which loads all the data I need and holds state `isInitializing`. While `isInitializing` is true I conditionally render a loading indicator, and when I have all my data loaded `dataObj1 && dataObj2` then I render my component.

You might also look into the hook `useLayoutEffect()` since you mention your component having the wrong size.

Comment: Yes, that is the common pattern, React makes it straightforward to display a loading indicator. What I'm asking about though, is whether the new features in React 18 allows keeping the old component around, instead of switching to a static loading indicator, which can be jarring visually.

Comment: So then my understanding is you're re-rendering a component but would like to delay painting until the component initializes with some async data, correct? Is there a reason useLayoutEffect() doesn't solve this for you? I mentioned both options because I'm not sure if you're mounting a new component or re-rendering an existing component.

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` is too fine-grained for this, it can't really help with delaying the updating of the DOM over several render cycles. The problem I'm trying to solve is well described [here in the official docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense#preventing-unwanted-fallbacks), however, the proposed solutions don't apply in my case due to the caveats outlined in the original post.

Comment: Ah, and I'm mounting a different component, rather than re-rendering an already mounted one.